# PugiXML C++ Newline handling issue: '\n\n' becomes '\\n\\n'

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, pugixml

Recently I have been using XML files for a localisation system for a game I am developing (which uses Cocos2d-X). I am using PugiXML to parse the XML localisation file. I have run into an issue when parsing English strings with newline (`\n`) characters in them. Put more accurately, in the XML file:

[image]

The problem is that PugiXML parses these `\n\n` characters into `\\n\\n`. Here's how it looks like on the debugger:

[image]

Note that the string the system is trying to translate is

`englishstring (englishstring   std::__1::string    "(We?[lcom]*e)(to|Regex).+\n\n(tap to continue)")`

and the string that pugixml is returning is

`engString(engString    std::__1::string    "(We?[lcom]*e)(to|Regex).+\\n\\n(tap to continue)")`

Obviously comparing these two strings fails, so nothing gets translated. Plus, Cocos2d-X won't draw a newline with `\\n` so setting all linebreaks to that isn't an option either.

I understand this is probably desired behaviour, but my question is: how can I fix/disable this behaviour? I have set my XML parsing mode to `pugi::parse_minimal` but it still returns `\\n` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ a backslash in a string must be escaped with another backslash. So if the text contains `\`, it will be displayed in a string as `"\\"`, even though it contains just a single backslash.

The character following the backslash, does not change this. `\n` in the xml are just two characters, one of them is a backslash. So `\n` becomes `"\\n"`

You seem to expect a newline in the xml. In that case you must use the xml entity `&#10;` to represent the newline. So instead of

```
<string16 englishstring="(We?[lcom]*e)(to|Regex).+\n\n(tap to continue)">
```

use this instead

```
<string16 englishstring="(We?[lcom]*e)(to|Regex).+&#10;&#10;(tap to continue)">
```

Or you could put a verbatim newline in the xml. That will look like this:

```
<string16 englishstring="(We?[lcom]*e)(to|Regex).+

(tap to continue)">
```

But not all xml parsers support that, I don't know about PugiXML.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. To elaborate, adding newlines to the XML doesn't really do anything with PugiXML, but &#10; seems to work just fine and is exactly what I needed. I also want to note that PugiXML needs its default parsing options for this to work, which means that using pugi::parse_minimal will not transform &#10; to \n.